# Count last rows until column value is equal to given value in myql

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose My table has only two column; among them one is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and another contains under line data...

```
A
B
C
A
A
```

I want to count **last rows** until desire **given** value found.

Suppose For,

```
A : 0 (Count From last to reach A)
C : 2 (Count From last to reach C)
B : 3 (Count From last to reach B)
```

Comment: I don't understand your results. Where does `USER: 3` come from?

Comment: if you count from last you get 3 rows to reach user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the highest ID for each item, and then count the number of rows that have higher IDs.

```
SELECT x.item, IFNULL(COUNT(y.id), 0) as count
FROM (SELECT item, MAX(id) AS lastid
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY item) AS x
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS y ON y.id > x.lastid
GROUP BY x.item
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ec1dcb/3)